# Javascript Array Elements Return undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

it is a very simple html document with a js script.

```
...
<script type = "text/javascript"> src = "xxx.js"></script>
...

<body>
  <ul id ="pics">
    <li><a href="A.jpg">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="A.jpg">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="A.jpg">A</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

the js file is:

```
var picspics = document.querySelectorAll("#pics ul > li > a");
alert(picspics[0]);
```

But it returned undefined, anyway, if just alert picspics, it will return "object nodelist", that sounds fine.

At first, I thought it is a dom loading problem, so I added

```
window.onload(){}
```

outside of my code, which also failed.

The all thing start with when I tried to use for loop to iterate all li > a  elements and add a onclick event, which shows in chrome console that the array of the a element is undefined, so I tried to debug it with alert function.

After which, I tried to unattach the js file, just loaded the html in chrome, and than type the js code in the console, it also failed as expected which I suggest that is the same to the window.onload function.

Anyway, what is my fault here? Should not the picspics variable return an array contains 3 a element? Then how could the first element is undefined?

Thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you are providing is `var picspics = document.querySelectorAll("#pics ul > li > a");` but `pics` **is** the `ul`. Change it to:

```
var picspics = document.querySelectorAll("ul#pics > li > a");
```

Comment: thnx, I have not enough reputation to vote up, but thank you.

Comment: Anytime! Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

The selector is wrong, it should be:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#pics > li > a");
```

Comment: thnx, I have not enough reputation to vote up, but thank you.